# Как вывести содержимое input без дублирования?

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

Я отслеживаю input событием "input keyup", для того что бы вывести сразу на экран и для фильтрации блоков по данным который ввел пользователь. Но когда я пытаюсь вывести уже окончательную версию того что ввел пользователь (через click), у меня происходит дублирования.

События:

```
$('#searchPermitted').on('input keyup', function (e) {
   //...
   addLiBlocked();
}
```

Как вывожу на экран:

```
function addLiBlocked() {
    $('.select_lists-choose-blocked').click(function () {

        $('#select_left ul')
            .append('<li>' + $('#searchPermitted').val() + '</li>');
    })
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас добавляется событие click при каждом вводе, вынесите его из функции, и функцию уберите и все ок будет)

Comment: СПАСИБО!!!! Я кучу всего перепробовал перепробовал. А как-то не подумал что можно и без функции обойтись))